# Connect to Google Drive from BroadcastReceiver / AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-play-services, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I need to connect and upload to Google Drive from within a *BroadcastReceiver* / *AsyncTask*. But when I try to connect my *GoogeApiClient* to the Google services I get:

`ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{XXXXX: android.os.BinderProxy@XXXXX}}`

I guess this happens due to the fact that there was no prompt to authorize my app yet.

**Question**: Is there any way to trigger that prompt within the *BroadcastReceiver*? *ConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult()* requires an *Activity* ...

**Alternative Question**: What's the best way to authorize my app? Do I need to guide the user to some activity where he grants access to GDrive, first?

Answer (score 2):

you should not be doing anything like this from a broadcast receiver. even if the user was signed in properly you still need to connect to google play services in the broadcast receiver. however a broadcast receiver only lasts for a few seconds and any uploading can take well over that.

Proper procedure IMO is to have the user sign-in when the app starts. When your broadcast receiver gets hit, start a special service that does all the work and if you get an error from google play service you do nothing in the service

Comment: Can that service trigger the authorization? From the BroadcastReceiver I start an AsyncTask - can that cause ANRs, too?

Comment: service cannot trigger auth, you need an activity. AsyncTasks in a service are totally normal

Comment: Okay, that means that I'll have to prompt the auth from my app directly. What if I created an Intent for that purpose if my app is not yet authorized? From within my AsyncTask.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Let's assume the user didn't authorize my app to use GDrive yet. My app receives the broadcast and tries to connect to GDrive. The ConnectionResult is the above so a new Intent is created to prompt the auth.

Comment: I dont see why not as long as you are starting an activity

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and report back.